# preventing updation of specific columns in sqlite from python

Tags: python, twisted

i am developing a twisted app which interacts with a sqlite backend, in the sqlite db there is a users table of which certain columns should not be updated if they already contain a value.
**one way of doing this would be to check the user table before each insert for existence of values in the columns of interest** and proceed accordingly , but this will be a performance killer and people familiar with twisted will know how cumbersome this can be, can someone suggest a better way of doing this .

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try the *INSERT OR IGNORE* variation of [the *INSERT* statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer **Jean** but that would kill the entire statement , **i need to update the rest of the columns and just leave the few specific columns of interest unaffected**

Comment: Perhaps ''INSERT OR REPLACE'' is for you, then.  Notice there are quite a few variations documented on the page I linked to.  Perhaps if you gave an example of the existing and replacement data for the case you're interested in, I could make a more definitive suggestion.  In your question, the phrase "should not be updated if they already contain a value" is somewhat confusing and I think not very well defined.  An example would make it easier to understand what behavior you want to achieve.